# Looping login after foolish compiz setting tweaks

Tags: unity, login, compiz, desktop-environments, dconf

After messing around with compiz and ignoring a perfectly good warning that told me this could make my desktop unusable... I am unable to login to Ubuntu (on my work lappy...yay), it simply loops back to the login screen. I jump to the terminal and have tried many things. I've tried removing compiz and reinstalling.

After trying a bunch of stuff, I eventually tried

```
unity --reset

# also tried
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

I get the message:

```
Warning: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
(process:2053): dconf-warning **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error 
spawning command line 'dbus-launch --
autolaunch=d98463f4c1aa983d9fd6d0df22f42686 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': 
Child process exited with code 1
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
Invalide MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycompiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0
compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: (core)
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: (core)
```

and running

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
```

returns

```
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

When I

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and then run the dconf command it seems successful but when I reboot, I still have no luck and am looping

I have tried to follow the instructions here, and also didnt work...

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328702

Is there another solution out there? Can i reboot and mount with the bootable USB maybe? I'd prefer not to lose all my work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be any more specific than "messing around with"?

Comment: ... and I wonder if `Invalide MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` points to a problem with your `~/.Xauthority` file - what are its ownership and permissions?

Comment: I was changing something with effects, nothing groundbreaking, certainly didn't think it would crash my computer.

Comment: The ~/.Xauthority file is owned by my user and user group.

Comment: Were you able to fix it? If Yes, how? Please help.